# Mysql (and Postgresql) performance on where = 1 and in(1)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Just out of curiosity, does anyone know if there is any major performance difference when you do...

```
Select something Where foo=1
```

...and...

```
Select something Where foo In(1)    #just one item not multiple
```

...both on Mysql and Postgresql in single or joined SQL queries.

The thing is I'm building [Ruby on Rails scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) and I'm wondering which approach is better,

crate one scope for multiple items (IN) and one for single item that will use equal (=)

```
scope :with_owner_ids, lambda{|owner_class, *ids| where(owner_type: owner_class.model_name, owner_id: ids.flatten)}
scope :with_owner, lambda{|owner| where(owner_type: owner.class.model_name, owner_id: owner.id)}
#... where `foos`.`owner_class`='User' and `foos`.`owner_id` = 15
```

or cleaner, create scope for multiple items (IN) and than just pass this scope to the other scope for single item (IN as well )

```
scope :with_owner_ids, lambda{|owner_class, *ids| where(owner_type: owner_class.model_name, owner_id: ids.flatten)}
scope :with_owner, lambda{|owner| with_owner_ids(owner.class, owner.id)}
#... where `foos`.`owner_class`='User' and `foos`.`owner_id` IN (15)
```

Comment: -1: Simply test it yourself.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see the differences, works in PostgreSQL and MySQL

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Although that could be good advice if it showed how as Frank did, I don't think it deserves a downvote. The question is on topic, is well written and is useful.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: It shows no research effort at all. That justifies a downvote as explained by the tooltip of the downvote button.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I think you misunderstood purpose of StackOwerflow, I'm asking if someone have done research of this kind, and if no-one does I'll do it myself :-\ ... this is community of exchanging knowledge by asking questions, not publishing researches

Comment: @equivalent8: See the [FAQ on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) - first heading "Do your homework".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostgreSQL example on a very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    a_id integer
    , t_id integer
);

COPY a
FROM STDIN;
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   4
\.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM a WHERE t_id IN (1);

 Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..36.75 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.056..0.059 rows=3 loops=1)
   Filter: (t_id = 1)
 Total runtime: 41.795 ms
```

From the `Filter: (t_id = 1)` part it is clear that `IN (1)` was translated into a simple equality check, therefore no difference between the two forms.

I leave the MySQL part to others :)

Comment: It might be interesting to see another example with an index on t_id (which would probably prove your point even better)

Comment: You will also occasionally see optimizers rewriting in the other direction: converting "...where x in ('a', 'b')..." to "...where x = 'a'.... union ... where x = 'b'..."

Comment: @LordPeter Could you give an example?  I've never seen that so far.

Comment: @dezso Oh dear! I can't put my hands on one just now. And perhaps more likely to be rewritten as ((x='a') or (x='b')). But just trying to illustrate that if queries are semantically the same, then the optimizer is generally free to rewrite them.

Comment: @LordPeter I'm wondering whether we are talking about the same PostgreSQL :)  The same testbed as above, `IN (1,2,3,4)` becomes `(t_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,4}'::integer[]))`

Comment: @dezso My amnesia was bothering me, and now I've found what I had in mind:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494205/let-oracle-transform-or-connected-predicates-into-union-all-operations. But you are quite correct, this relates to Oracle not PostgreSQL. However, I found it very interesting because it seems counter-intuitive that "union" could ever be preferred over "in" or "or", until you consider parallel processing situations.

Comment: @LordPeter If I understand you correctly, then my answer is: a UNION may be regarded as a SARGable version of an or, say `... WHERE a = 1 OR a = 2` (which is non-sargable) versus `... WHERE a = 1 UNION ... WHERE a = 2` (which is).  If the optimizer is clever enough, it can translate `OR` into something sargable - be it a `UNION` or, like above, ` = ANY(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I played around with MySQL EXPLAIN:

**equal**

```
mysql> explain extended select * from document_name_ownerships as dno join document_names as dn on dn.id = dno.document_name_id  where dn.id = 18 ;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dn    | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dno   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |   81 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
2 

rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**in()**

```
mysql> explain extended select * from document_name_ownerships as dno join document_names as dn on dn.id = dno.document_name_id  where dn.id in(18) ;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dn    | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | dno   | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |   81 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

So it seems the **equal (=)** was negligibly faster than **IN()** when it comes to one record

but interestingly, when I done several items the results were same:

```
mysql> explain extended select * from document_name_ownerships as dno join document_names as dn on dn.id = dno.document_name_id  where dn.id = 18 or dn.id=17  or dn.id=19;
> (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain extended select * from document_name_ownerships as dno join document_names as  dn on dn.id = dno.document_name_id  where dn.id in (18, 17, 19);
> (0.00 sec)
```

but don't know if this results can be trusted on live server because on my development machine I got SSD drives ... but it seems the same to me

---

**Updated**

with 70000 records

```
select * from document_name_ownerships as dno join document_names as dn on dn.id = dno.document_name_id  where dn.id = 60811;
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

select * from document_name_ownerships as dno join document_names as dn on dn.id = dno.document_name_id  where dn.id in( 60811);
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

multiple

```
select * from document_name_ownerships as dno join document_names as dn on dn.id = dno.document_name_id  where dn.id in( 60800, 11111, 22222, 40000);
4 rows in set (0.07 sec)

select * from document_name_ownerships as dno join document_names as dn on dn.id = dno.document_name_id  where dn.id = 60800 or dn.id = 11111 or dn.id = 22222 or dn.id = 40000;
4 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: hmmmmm... maybe the difference was due to system load or something, I got now 0.00 sec in all above examples    :-\

Comment: Looks like you need an index on dno.document_name_id. And did you test on a table with some serious amount of data? A query on a (almost) empty table is always fast, no matter what.

Comment: hmm yeah, good point, guess I didn't thought about that, I'll update this once I do some database seeding with more records, currently there is like 80 records which is ridiculous

Comment: And the results from EXPLAIN? Is the database using an index for these queries?